# How to transform Multimap<A,B> to Iterable<C>

Tags: guava

How to transform `Multimap<A,B>` to `Iterable<C>` , where `C(Iterable<B> iterableB)`?

For example.

`Iterable<String> names` = ["Alice", "Anna", "Ben", "Chris", "Charlie"]

`Multimap<Integer,String> namesStartWith` = { [1 , ["Alice", "Anna"]], [2 , ["Ben"]], [3,["Chris", "Charlie"]] }

For each `Entry<Integer , List<String>>` transform to Names.

```
ImmutableListMultimap<Integer, String> example = Multimaps.index(newArrayList("Alice", "Anna", "Ben", "Chris", "Charlie"), new Function<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String input) {
        return input.startsWith("A") ? 1 : input.startsWith("B") ? 2 : 3;
    }
});

List<Names> names = newArrayList();
for (Integer number : example.keys()) {
    names.add(new Names(number,example.get(number)));
}
return names;

private class Names {

    int startWith;
    List<String> names;

    public Names(int startWith, List<String> names) {
        this.startWith = startWith;
        this.names = names;
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this using Guava?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @mota This question is incredibly ambiguous. Please refer to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It sounds like you already have your answer.  There's not an unambiguously better answer, though it might help to iterate over `asMap().entrySet()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the map as follows.

```
for(Integer key : map.keySet()) {
  for(String value : map.get(key)) {
  }
}
```